# Could not delete caches dir when compile Kotlin in Intellij IDE

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kapt

My project use plugin kapt to generate mapper.

When run app then can not compile Kotlin (image below)
If remove plugin kapt then it not happend.
To resolve I must restart Intellij IDE. Take more time.

This error probably only happen on windows
[image]

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Or you can try: Open Task Manager => Find & kill Java tasks run in Intellij IDEA task. After this build project normal.

Answer (score 7):

This is a Kotlin bug, you can vote and watch it for updates: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36253. A workaround is to kill the running Java processes.

Comment: how do you kill the running java process?

Comment: For killing the Java processes you'll have to go to the *Task Manager* -> *Details* and check for the (multiple) instances of Java

Comment: This is not only in Intelli J but also happening in Android Studio.

Answer (score 7):

I have this problem almost every build (Android Studio stable + Artic Fox).

**Manual Solution (try this first, if it works continue)**

Task manager > Processes > End "OpenJDK Platform Library" tasks
(sometimes it's standalone, sometimes it's under "Android Studio")

OR

Task manager > Details > End "java.exe" tasks

**Automated Solution**

1. Create a new end-java.bat file
2. Content of .bat file: `taskkill /f /IM java.exe`
3. Right click end-java.bat file > create shortcut
4. Right click the shortcut > properties
5. Add shortcut key (e.g. ALT + CTRL + 1)
6. ALT + CTRL + 1 will now fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache

```
Add this code : 

    // To re-enable the build cache, either delete the following 
// line or set the property to 'true'. 
android.enableBuildCache=false
```

After that clean project and restart android studio

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to use a different JDK (e.g. OpenJDK). It helped me.

*File -> Project Structure -> SDK Locations -> JDK Location*

Comment: Nope. Switching to OpenJDK 11.0.12.7 did not help for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can reboot the system, it will help. But this problem will return soon. This is the bag of Android Studio 4.2 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36253

Comment: It is not needed to reboot the whole system, as the bug will reappear sooner or later